# Query which deals with comparision of 2 or more records of a table

Tags: sql

I want to compare 2 or more rows in sql.

I have a table `ABC`. It has primary key column `id`. It has 2 more columns, `id2` and `startdate`.

I want to find all those `id`s whose `startdate` is different from that of `id2`. `id2` is just an extension of id.

For eg: if `id` is `123`, then `id2` is `123-1`.

**UPDATE: Example according to OP's comment**

If table has

```
id      id2   startdate 
123-1   123   0408 
123           0408 
124           0508 
124-1   124   0608
```

the query should display

```
id      id2   startdate 
124           0508 
124-1   124   0608
```

where startdate is different.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Also tag the dbms used.

Comment: if table has
id/id2/startdate
123-1/123/0408
123//0408
124//0508
124-1/124/0608
as shown above. quesry should display
124//0508
124-1/124/0608 where startdate is different

Comment: @user3528745: Good example. You should have added it to your question though, as I have done now. And as jarlh mentioned: you should always tag your DBMS with SQL queries. MySQL has another SQL dialect as SQL Server for instance, so a solution for one of the two may not work for the other.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for records for which **exists** another record with a different startdate:

```
select *
from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where (other.id = mytable.id2 or other.id2 = mytable.id)
  and other.startdate <> mytable.startdate
);
```